# Record water / liquid simulation animation to then transform it?

Tags: physics, transforms, fluid-simulation

is it possible to record an animation created through water liquid simulation on a plane. Then fix this transformations that where recorded so you can transform the object without recalculation the water simulation.

Example:

1. I have a ball falling onto a horizontal plane causing a wave animation.
2. Then I rotate the plane 90deg to make it vertical. But the simulated wave, stays exactly as it was (and is now horizontal)

Is there a way to achieve this?